# In Jest, how do you mock a TypeScript class with dependencies?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Given this relatively contrived class that gets a single record from Elasticsearch (or any datastore for that matter):

```
export default class UserRepoImpl implements UserRepo {
  constructor(private readonly esClient: ElasticsearchClient) {}

  public async getUser(id: string): Promise<User> {
    const response = await this.esClient.request('GET', `/users/_doc/${id}`);

    return response._source;
  }
}
```

How do I write a test that will instantiate a `UserRepoImpl` for me but insert a *mocked ElasticsearchClient* as the argument to the constructor?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a mock client within your test like this:

```
const client: jest.Mocked<ElasticsearchClient> = {
  request: jest.fn()
}
```

which will statically check the type of the resolved value when passed:

example test:

```
describe('UserRepoImpl', () => {
  describe('given a client', () => {
    const client: jest.Mocked<ElasticsearchClient> = {
      request: jest.fn()
    }
    describe('getUser', () => {
      beforeAll(() => {
        client.request.mockResolvedValue({
          _source: {
            id: '3'
          }
        })
      })

      it('should return user by Id', async () => {
        const userRepo = new UserRepoImpl(client)
        await expect(userRepo.getUser("3")).resolves.toEqual({
          id: '3'
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: It's `await expect`.

Comment: `resolves` is asynchronous by nature. It's physically impossible to synchronously assert what native promise resolves to. A promise that successful `resolves` assertion returns is ignored, a promise that failed one won't make a test to fail but will result in uncaught promise rejection.

Comment: @EstusFlask aggeed. Also returning a promise would have the same result

Comment: @Teneff When I am mocking the client, I am getting the error: `Type '{ request: Mock<any, any>; }' is not assignable to type 'Mocked<ElasticsearchClient>'.   Type '{ request: Mock<any, any>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ElasticsearchClient': awsHttps, endpoint`

Comment: @JeffreyWen check if you are using the latest package versions of jest and @types/jest

Comment: @Teneff My jest is 26.1.0, @types/jest is 26.0.3, and ts-jest is 26.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Here is the unit test solution:

`userRepoImpl.ts`:

```js
interface User {}
interface UserRepo {
  getUser(id: string): Promise<User>;
}
interface ElasticsearchClient {
  request(method: string, endpoint: string): Promise<{ _source: any }>;
}
export default class UserRepoImpl implements UserRepo {
  constructor(private readonly esClient: ElasticsearchClient) {}

  public async getUser(id: string): Promise<User> {
    const response = await this.esClient.request('GET', `/users/_doc/${id}`);

    return response._source;
  }
}
```

`userRepoImpl.test.ts`:

```js
import UserRepoImpl from './userRepoImpl';

describe('62603645', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const mUser = { name: 'wen' };
    const mEsClient = { request: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({ _source: mUser }) };
    const userRepoImpl = new UserRepoImpl(mEsClient);
    const actual = await userRepoImpl.getUser('1');
    expect(actual).toEqual(mUser);
    expect(mEsClient.request).toBeCalledWith('GET', '/users/_doc/1');
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/62603645/userRepoImpl.test.ts (10.988s)
  62603645
    ✓ should pass (5ms)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 userRepoImpl.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.27s
```

Comment: I appreciate your very detail-oriented solution. Do you know if there is a difference between your variable `mClient` and `client` (solution provided by @teneff)

Comment: I am getting an error when I'm instantiating a new instance with the mocked client: `Argument of type '{ request: Mock<any, any>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ElasticsearchClient'.   Type '{ request: Mock<any, any>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ElasticsearchClient': awsHttps, endpoint`